# How can I filter get_terms with post meta

Tags: terms

I have a custom post type `product` with custom taxonomy `web_cat` and I have set a custom field `expiration_date` to each of the posts of this type.  I'm using that field in a pre_get_posts to hide posts that expired like this:

```
function rt_webinar_pre_query_two($query){
   if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'product' ) {
    $today = date('Ymd'); // Today's date
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'event_date' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC');
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'expiration_date',
                'compare' => '>=',
                'value'   => date('Ymd'),
                'type'    => 'numeric',
            )
        ) );
   }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rt_webinar_pre_query_two' );
```

This filters my posts on my archive page correctly.

I want a list of all terms as links to the tax archives.

I created that link list with this function:

```
function list_webinar_categories() {
    $webcats = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'web_cat',
        'hide_empty' => true,
        'parent' => 0
    ) );
    if ( !empty($webcats) ) {
        $catlist = '<ul>';
        foreach ($webcats as $webcat) {
            $catlist .= '<li><a href="'.esc_url( get_term_link( $webcat ) ).'">'.$webcat->name.'</a></li>';
        }
        $catlist .= '</ul>';
        return $catlist;
    }
}
add_shortcode ('webinar-categories', 'list_webinar_categories');
```

The problem is that this function is not being filtered by my pre_get_posts.  So it will create a list of categories but will not hide empty categories based on my expiration date.  This results in a direct 404 page if that term has all expired posts or a tax page that has links that go to 404 pages.  Is there any way to apply the expiration_date exclusion to get_terms?  (something along the lines of `if_empty`)

I thought about adding

```
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
           'key'       => 'expiration_date',
           'value'     => date('Ymd'),
           'compare'   => '>='
        )),
```

But that would only check if the terms have the expiration date.

I also tried adding a 2nd pre_get_posts:

```
function rt_webinar_pre_query_three($query){
   if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_tax() && $query->query_vars['taxonomy'] == 'web_cat') {
    $today = date('Ymd'); // Today's date
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'event_date' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC');
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'expiration_date',
                'compare' => '>=',
                'value'   => date('Ymd'),
                'type'    => 'numeric',
            )
        ) );
   }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rt_webinar_pre_query_three' );
```

However no changes to the terms archives.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output a list of terms that are assigned to the posts in the current query, you could use something like this in your template:

```
global $wp_query;
$terms = [];
foreach ( $wp_query->get_posts() as $item ) {
    $item_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $item->ID, 'web_cat' );
    $terms[]    = $item_terms;
}
$unique = array_unique( array_merge(...$terms), SORT_REGULAR );
foreach ( $unique as $t ) {
    var_dump( $t->term_id);
}
```

Comment: No, this is going to be in the sidebar and fully separate from posts